# How to fetch data from the result of an entity class in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate and getting data from two tables.

I create two Entity classes **User.java** and **Profession.java** to fetch data from the tables user_table and user_profession.

user_table contains user information and user_profession contains the profession of user with uid as a foreign key. I am getting one record from user_table and getting the profession of that user from user_profession

Here is **User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_table")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="full_name")
private String fullName;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="u_id")
private List<Profession> prof;  


public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<Profession> getProf() {
    return prof;
}

public void setProf(List<Profession> prof) {
    this.prof = prof;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

}
```

I used **@OneToMany** annotation here to connect with Profession.java because i want to get the profession of user
. Now i got the profession of user but now i want those records from profession table whichs contains same profession as i fetched before.

Here is my Profession.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profession")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Profession implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="u_id")
private long uid;

@Column(name="profession")
private String profession;

@Column(name="type")
private String professionType;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="u_id")
private List<User> prof;  



//Getters and setters

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(long uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getProfession() {
    return profession;
}

public void setProfession(String profession) {
    this.profession = profession;
}


public String getProfessionType() {
    return professionType;
}

public void setProfessionType(String professionType) {
    this.professionType = professionType;
}


}
```

Here is my **Dao** class

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Session session = null;
Transaction tx = null;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<User> getUserById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
    List results = cr.list();
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return results;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<Profession> getProfessionById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Profession.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("u_id", id));
    List results = cr.list();
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return results;
}
```

Here is my **Controller**

```
    @Autowired
SubscribeDataService subscribeService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<User> getSubscriber(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

    List<User> user = null;

    try {
        user = subscribeService.getUserById(id);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return user;
}
```

Comment: So you have a `ManyToMany` relation between users and professions?

Comment: no i have one two many relationship

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Your mapping doesn't make much sense. Does a user really have many professions? Why do you have a List<User> in Profession?

Comment: Well, your user has multiple professions, and your profession has multiple users. Last time I checked, that's called a many-to-many relation.

Comment: Actually i want to use criteria and it returns list..so used List<User> . But here i am fetching only one record of user

Comment: yes  yes. actually there is many to many relationship

Comment: but how can i get the users of that profession

Comment: So, you have a table for professions (containing, for example "teacher", "developer", "mechanic") and a table for users (containing for example "Joe", "Alice", "Mike"). And each user has several professions, for example; Joe is developer and mechanic, and Alice is teacher and developer. If that is right, it's a many-to-many association, and you need to change the design completely: forget about uid in profession: you need a join table. And you need to use ManyToMany in your mapping.

Comment: okay..but i am fetching only one user at a time from user table after that i will fetch multiple users of the profession

Comment: So, load the profession from the database, then call getUsers() on that profession, and that will return the users of that profession.

Comment: okay..but where @ManyToMany will be used?

Comment: and if i use @ManyToMany anf the result has only one profession then will there be any problem?

Comment: 2 mistakes I can see is you don't have one-to-many, but many-to-many. Is the code even working because you have to create an intermediate table for many-to-many to work. Second, you call getProfessionById, you pass ID and you expect a List?? Ideally if it's an unique key you are passing, you will get only one entry. Also, your associations are messed up....

Comment: I will attempt to improve your code and paste an answer. I hope it works. Gimme 10.

Comment: Also, please use getSession.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @We are Borg  ..I am waiting for your code :)

Comment: Why are you saving userid in Profession directly, it's available in association. This is redundancy at its best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your User class :

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name="user_table")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Profession> prof;  
    // getters and setters
    }
```

here is profession class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profession")
// i have no idea why you need such JSONIgnore, but ok
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Profession implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="u_id")
private long uid;

@Column(name="profession")
private String profession;

@Column(name="type")
private String professionType;

@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "userid", nullable = false)
    private User usersProfession
// getters and metters
}
```

Now comes you DAO class :

```
 private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DAOClasname(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

// I am presuming you want user and passing user id.
    // Don't just throw Exception, use something meaningful
public User getUserById(long id){
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
return (User)session.get(User.class,id);

}

// I am presuming you are passing user id and expect users profession
// Don't just throw Exception, use something meaningful
public List<Profession> getProfessionById(long id){
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("from Profession as P where p.usersProfession.userId=:id");
   query.setParameter("id",id);
return query.list();
}
```

For DAO class, please use interface, and your DAOImpl class should implement these methods in DAOImpl class. If anyone can suggest corrections, those are welcome.

Comment: so i need to create third table Profession in my db?

Comment: No, you dont...one-to-many doesn't require extra tables. Just keep those two tables.. Please change the id variable names appropriately.. I just typed in on my own.

Comment: p.usersProfession.userId  .. what is userId ?

Comment: getting this error...  org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: artle.subscribe.model.Profession column: u_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: That's exactly what I said you are doing, you have redundant mapping. Remove private long uid; from your Profession class.

Comment: Did you use interface and annotated your service layer with Service and Transactional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85283/discussion-between-nadeem-ahmed-and-we-are-borg).

Comment: No chat, I have helped you enough. Read spring documentation, post a new question and wait for users to answer. I have answered the current question you had. Mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I cannot do your project for you man. Try n understand. Use the annotation, search on google whats that error, there are many links.